# How would I plot a function f(x,y) (technically a field) as a colour gradient in Pylab?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am current trying to plot a function `f(x,y)`, which is technically a vector `A(r)` and a field if I am being nit picky.

The plot:

I want the plot to be done over an XY graph, where `f(x,y)` is represented as a colour gradient.

For example near the point of origin for the field, `f(x,y)` will be larger and therefore darker in colour!

Any help is appreciated, and I also understand there are some tutorials which I have looked at. The problem with these is that I am struggling to understand why they all use syntax like:

`from something import *` or `import something as something else`

Why would you do that, I have always been taught to simply do:

```
import numpy
import pylab
```

I then struggle to understand the rest of the program because the syntax is unclear and I can't find a tutorial which is black and white in its answer!

Comment: This is basic Python syntax, you should [check out these tutorials for help with importing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers).

Comment: Also, if you write code, explain it like you would to a simpleton please! I am physicist by trade hahahah!

Comment: What do you mean by "a vector A(r) and a field"?  I ask because vectors aren't well represented by colors.  But for plotting a 2D scalar function represented by colors, a common choice is a contour plot and here's and example: http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#contour-plots

Comment: @tom10: We could assume he's plotting magnetic vector potential, which is typically represented in space by an object with the properties of `np.array(Xmax, Ymax, Zmax, 3)`.

Comment: I am also a physicist, that is no excuse.

Comment: Wow, SO's been harsh here :). Some hints about how to get on their better side: one question per question at most (never put several in at once), try and give what you've done so far, even if you've only managed to find a few tutorials. And if you have gotten stuck on some tutorials, explain what *in particular* is confusing you. Also, if you ever say "I have this thing", **show** us "this thing". A small snippet is way better than a few paragraphs of prose.

Answer (score 1):

The user has two questions: Why alias your imports, and how to "plot" a variable of two parameters.  The reason to alias imports is to make code more compact, and therefore easier to read.  Packages have nice long names that are unlikely to collide with each other.  It is the users' responsibility to keep the aliases unique within a package. `from something import *` is convenient but not so good for maintainability, since it obscures what is being imported.  For the sake of relating this to Physics, it's like writing G=w*e^2, and expecting somebody to figure out "I use G for energy, w for mass and e for the speed of light."

To plot a function of two variables:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x,y):
   "Arbitrary function of two variables for demonstration"
   return np.sinc(x**2 + y**2)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01), np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01))
plt.imshow(f(x, y))
plt.show()
```

If you really want gray-scale, use `plt.imshow(f(x, y), cmap=plt.cm.gray)` and if it bothers you that the large values of `f(x, y)` are light rather than dark, replace `f` with `-f`.